# Vagrant upn "unknown state"

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

After running vagrant up command, I get this error:

```
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Importing base box 'bento/ubuntu-16.04-i386'...
==> default: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
==> default: Checking if box 'bento/ubuntu-16.04-i386' is up to date...
==> default: Setting the name of the VM: vagrant_default_1494490054450_47471
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 8000 (guest) => 8000 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 8080 (guest) => 8080 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 5000 (guest) => 5000 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
The guest machine entered an invalid state while waiting for it
to boot. Valid states are 'starting, running'. The machine is in the
'unknown' state. Please verify everything is configured
properly and try again.

If the provider you're using has a GUI that comes with it,
it is often helpful to open that and watch the machine, since the
GUI often has more helpful error messages than Vagrant can retrieve.
For example, if you're using VirtualBox, run `vagrant up` while the
VirtualBox GUI is open.

The primary issue for this error is that the provider you're using
is not properly configured. This is very rarely a Vagrant issue.
```

When I look at the virtualbox GUI everything seems to be fine, it's in running state and I can even log in into linux. Im running it on Windows 10 OS, Vagrant 1.9.4, VirtualBox 5.1.22

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved the problem. I did not have virtualization enabled on my laptop.

Comment: I am facing the same problem but my virtualization seems to be enabled.